# Rust fltk compile Err

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, fltk

I'm trying to build a small application from GitHub on Windows 10 but it fails even though I have MingW(codeblocks) in Path:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `fltk-sys v1.3.7`
 curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
  thread 'main' panicked at 'Download bundled libraries from "https://github.com/fltk-rs/fltk-rs/releases/download/1.3.7/lib_x64-windows-msvc.tar.gz" failed', G:\apps\CargoHome\.cargo\registry\src\mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd\fltk-sys-1.3.7\build\bundled.rs:42:13
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

```ini
[dependencies]
dscom = {path = "../dscom"}
zstd = "0.9"
fltk-sys="1.2.20"
fltk = { version = "1.2.20",features = ["fltk-bundled"] }
```

Comment: [dependencies]
dscom = {path = "../dscom"}

zstd = "0.9"
fltk-sys="1.2.20"
fltk = { version = "1.2.20",features = ["fltk-bundled"] }

Comment: paltform is windows10

Comment: Are you able to download this archive manually, by following the link in the error message? If not, that's the problem with your network configuration.

Comment: maybe the network.but i can download file from github by browser，the cargo ..i don`t konw why.

Comment: oh！ after setting  $env:https_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:10809" it·s ok

Answer (score 0):

`fltk-sys` uses a build script. `fltk-sys-1.3.7\build\bundled.rs`

It tries to download the file `https://github.com/fltk-rs/fltk-rs/releases/download/1.3.7/lib_x64-windows-msvc.tar.gz`.

But it failed to get the file. `curl` returned the error `404`

> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404

This means that the file was not found.
Try downloading the file manually and see if that works. (it worked for me, so file exists) You can also fine links to the file here: https://github.com/fltk-rs/fltk-rs/releases

If that does not work, there might be something wrong with your internet settings.

Comment: Thanks！ And   after download the file Where to put them？ To Cargo Home？or the project Home

Comment: I see in the comments above you have figures it out.

[ > oh! after setting $env:https_proxy="127.0.0.1:10809" it's ok ]